# TCL character class

Tags: tcl

According to the [TCL man page for "string match"](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M17) I should be able to do a character class.  A simple example:

```
set rev revA

if { [string match "revA*" $rev } {
   puts "revA"
} elseif {[string match "revB" $rev]} {
   puts "revB"
} elseif {[string match "rev[CD]" $rev]} {
   puts "revC or D"
} else {
   puts "none"
}
```

Without the "rev[CD]" section it works fine but as shown above I get:

```
% tclsh tmp.tcl
 missing close-bracket
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real error is that you are actually missing a close bracket in the first `if`

```
if { [string match "revA*" $rev } {
# .............................^
```

Don't forget that `[brackets]` also signify Tcl's [command substitution](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M11), and command substitution [happens within double quotes](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8). You need to either escape the open bracket or use different quotes:

```
} elseif {[string match "rev\[CD]" $rev]} {
```

```
} elseif {[string match {rev[CD]} $rev]} {
```

However, it's more efficient in this case, instead of cascading if-elseifs, to use [`switch`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/switch.htm)

```
switch -glob -- $rev {
    "revA*"   {puts "revA"}
    "revB"    {puts "revB"}
    {rev[CD]} {puts "revC or D"}
    default   {puts "none"}
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you much.  Bad example in my original post.  The actual error I was getting was 'invalid command name "CD"' but you provided the fix for that in your answer too.  Thanks for the info on switch as well.